Search and Replace all case insensitive feature in Typescript
I am working on a find and replace feature where all instances of a search phrase will be replaced by the replacement text. E.g.
Example 1:
str = "This is a $1000 string $100000"
search = "$1000" 
replacement = "1 thousand"
result = "This is a 1 thousand string 1 thousand00"

str = "This is a Case insensitive example"
search = "case" 
replacement = "Base"
result = "This is a Base insensitive example"

This is what I have so far.
let searchText = "$1000"
let text = "This is $1000 text"
// Create a regex pattern for the search text
let pattern = new RegExp(search_text, "gi");
// Replace the search text with the replacement text
let finalText = text.replace(pattern, "1 thousand");


What I get instead is "This is $1000 text" nothing changes.

Escape the $ - it's a meta character for regular expression patterns meaning "end of line" or "end of text" (depending on the multiline flag)

It's not a great idea to create a regex from literal search text. You have to escape such text first, maybe by using some implementation of RegExp.escape, as shown here. See linked q/a above for more information.
